# Why this JSON object cannot be parsed?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

In my JavaScript file,

The declaring and json parse for the ajax response text is like this:

```
var subcats = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

The supposed responseText for the parsing is like this:

```
{"presubcatId":"1","precatId":"1","presubcatName":"HR Manager"}{"presubcatId":"2","precatId":"1","presubcatName":"Marketing Manager"}
```

and it gives me this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 2 column 64 of the JSON data
```

what's the syntax error? help

Comment: Yes, that is not a valid JSON string (or a string at all). You can read the spec [here](https://www.json.org/).

Comment: Run it through [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/), the error stands out instanly.

Comment: I guess it should look like this
[{"presubcatId":"1","precatId":"1","presubcatName":"HR Manager"},{"presubcatId":"2","precatId":"1","presubcatName":"Marketing Manager"}]

Comment: Yes got that. I fetched data by rows which caused  Invalid parse I think. Now I tried fetch all method it was okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)() method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. So you can use it like this if you have a single item:

`JSON.parse('{"presubcatId":"1", "precatId":"1", "presubcatName":"HR Manager"}');`

but in your case you have multiple items that should be wrapped inside brackets `[]` and separated by commas or there is SyntaxError:

`JSON.parse('[{"presubcatId":"1", "precatId":"1", "presubcatName":"HR Manager" }, { "presubcatId": "2", "precatId": "1", "presubcatName": "Marketing Manager"}]');`

```js
var string = '[{"presubcatId":"1", "precatId":"1", "presubcatName":"HR Manager" }, { "presubcatId": "2", "precatId": "1", "presubcatName": "Marketing Manager"}]';

var json = JSON.parse(string);

console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON have multiple elements and therefore should be wrap in an Array/List like this

```
[{"presubcatId":"1","precatId":"1","presubcatName":"HR Manager"}{"presubcatId":"2","precatId":"1","presubcatName":"Marketing Manager"}]
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. You need change it like this:

```
[{"presubcatId":"1","precatId":"1","presubcatName":"HR Manager"},{"presubcatId":"2","precatId":"1","presubcatName":"Marketing Manager"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

your JSON data is invalid so that you are having problem,

```js
var temp=[];
temp=[{"presubcatId":"1","precatId":"1","presubcatName":"HR Manager"},{"presubcatId":"2","precatId":"1","presubcatName":"Marketing Manager"}]

console.log(JSON.stringify(temp))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON have multiple elements. So it must be treated like Array. See below image.

Below is valid JSON structure.

```
[{"presubcatId":"1","precatId":"1","presubcatName":"HR Manager"},{"presubcatId":"2","precatId":"1","presubcatName":"Marketing Manager"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your json object is not a valid json. You can check it on this site. It helps me a lot when I need to format or validate a Json object.

https://jsonlint.com/

Here is your json object formatted and it says what you are missing.

[image: Json validated with jsonlint]